# Updating a relation without loading navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

I have two entities `Order` and `Customer` with following relation:

`Order` *-1`Customer`

(`Customer` is a navigation property in `Order`)

If I define `CustomerId` as foreign key in the `Order` easily I can update `Customer` of an `Order` by following code:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext)
{
    var ord = new Order{ Id = 1, CustomerId = 10 };
    ctx.Orders.Attach(ord);
    ctx.Entry(ord).Property(x=>x.CustomerId).IsModified = true;
    ctx.SaveChanges();  
}
```

But if I dont define `CustomerId` in `Order`, Is there any similar way to update this relation without loading `Customer` entity?

the following code cause runtime error:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext)
{
    var ord = new Order{ Id = 1, Customer = new Customer {Id = 10}};
    ctx.Orders.Attach(ord);
    ctx.Entry(ord).Property(x=>x.Customer).IsModified = true;
    ctx.SaveChanges();  
}
```

because we can not use `Property()`for navigation properties.

Comment: So is there a customerId field in the order class at all? this is hard to understand

Comment: @TheGeneral: yes

Comment: *But if I dont define CustomerId in Order* -- Why not? That would be the easiest (and obvious) way to achieve what you describe (*update this relation without loading Customer entity*).

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Explain "cause runtime error". Also, what information modeling & database design reference are you using/following? What do you have against FKs? You seem to be trying to solve a non-problem. PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2):

Declare both classes with navigation properties to each other. Mark one of the tables (the dependent table) with the `ForeignKey` attribute on its Primary Key.

```
public class Customer
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     ...

     public int CustomerId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
     public Customer Customer{ get; set; }
}
```

After Remigrate you can do this like:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext)
{
    var ord = new Order{ Id = 1, Customer = new Customer {Id = 10}};
    ctx.Orders.Add(ord);
    ctx.SaveChanges();  
}
```

Comment: but I don't want to define foreign key.

Comment: @Masoud Why not? So `EF` can't understand relation between them.